# Why is Select2 calculating the wrong size?

Tags: jquery-select2

No matter what I do, Select2 seems to calculate the wrong width and the option text gets cut off.  I have tried this in both Chrome and Firefox and simplified things down to almost nothing with no success.  Is this just a flawed plugin or is there something I'm missing that will make it calculate the correct size?

```js
$('select').select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select><option value="123">test option</option></select>
```

I have also tried setting `width : "auto"` in the Select2 options but this has the undesirable effect of making the width dynamic, i.e., it changes as you select options.

Answer (score 0):

[Select2 documentation container width](https://select2.org/appearance#container-width)

> Select2 will try to match the width of the original element as closely
> as possible. Sometimes this isn't perfect, in which case you may
> manually set the width configuration option

See below

```js
$('#default').select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

default width<br>
<select><option value="123">test option</option></select><br>
<select id="default"><option value="123">test option</option></select>
```

You can use an alternative solution by taking the width of the select element with [jQuery outerWidth](https://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) and adding an additional number of pixels when setting the width parameter of the select2 plugin

```js
$('.workaround').each(function() {
  let width = $(this).outerWidth(false);
  // console.log(width);
  $(this).select2({
    width: ((width + 30) + 'px')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

Workaround using select element width + 30px
<br>
<select class="workaround">
  <option value="123">test option</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="workaround">
  <option value="123">test option</option>
  <option value="456">test larger size option</option>
  <option value="789">test extremely larger size option</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="workaround">
  <option value="123">test option</option>
  <option value="456">test larger size option</option>
  <option value="789">test extremely larger size option</option>
  <option value="101">test really extremely larger size option</option>
</select>
```

You can set a width css inline select tag

```js
$('#widthInline').select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="widthInline" style="width: 150px;">
  <option value="123">test option</option>
</select> width 150px by inline style
```

You can use css class in select tag

```js
$('#widthByClass').select2();
```

```css
.widthByClass {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="widthByClass" class="widthByClass">
  <option value="123">test option</option>
</select> width 250px by css class
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this is not a question about how to override styles with CSS and you haven't answered my question: "*Why is Select2 calculating the wrong size?*" OR "*... is there something I'm missing that will make it calculate the correct size?*".  Setting a static width does not address the plugin's ability to calculate the correct width. Neither does adjusting the width after the element is rendered.

Comment: Furthermore, if the plugin can't handle even the most basic MRE as I've provided in my question, I suspect it is just garbage and the docs quote "*Sometimes this isn't perfect*" would be a massive understatement. That being only a suspicion, I am still open to the idea that I might have overlooked something.